# Trying to get my for loop working

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, logic

So at this point I have no idea why my `for` loop doesn't work. It's probably just an minor mistake but I cant find it so I'd appreciate your help. This is how it looks like:

```
int[] values = new int[array1.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (int x = 0; x >= array1[i][0] && x <= array1[i][2]; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y >= array1[i][1] && y <= array1[i][3]; y++) {
            values[i] += array2[x][y];
        }
    }
}
```

Numbers I'm using to test it on and some context:

Both arrays are 2D,
`array1`  looks like this:

[image: array1]

(`array1.length` = `8`) and `array2` like this:

[image: array2]

`array1` holds coordinates of left-top and right-bottom corner of the area in `array2` so for example `0 0 2 1` are coordinates for `array2[0][0]` and `array2[2][1]` and I'm trying to get my `for` loop to add all numbers in the area. So for this example it would add those four numbers:

[image]

My output is: `3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... these 4 underlined numbers should not be for coordinates from 0,0 to 1,1 (ie 0 0 1 1) ?

Comment: So basically it should "create" an rectangle between coordinates (in this example (0,0) and (2,1)) and add all numbers inside of it.

Comment: Just to clarify, what would be the desired output in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use explicit variable names not to do errors in meaning. 
Moreover, start your loop at expected coordinates. So your loop can be written like this:

```
int[] values = new int[array1.length];
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    int fromX = array1[i][0];
    int fromY = array1[i][1];
    int toX = array1[i][2];
    int toY = array1[i][3];

    for (int x = fromX; x <= toX; x++) {
        for (int y = fromY; y <= toY; y++) {
            values[i] += array2[x][y];
        }
    }
}
```

You can check the result:

```
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( values) );
// Output is [3, 0, 4, -2, 0, 1, -2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this (add <= and >=) and change statring value.  Also consider filling "values" with zeros since you're summing it up.

```
                for (int x = array1[i][0]; x >= array1[i][0] && x =< array1[i][2]; x++) {
                    for (int y = array1[i][1]; y >= array1[i][1] && y =< array1[i][3]; y++) {
                        values[i] += array2[x][y];
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Now my output is ' 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` instead of `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`